# React route broken on build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm trying to create a routing for react app.
I set my routing inside index.js, and use a flag to route to a diffrent screen for a logged in  users.

My problem is that the routing don't work after doing 'npm run build'

this is the code

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
            loggedIn ? (
                    <Redirect to="/Login"/>
                ) : (
                    <Slider />
                )
        )}/>
        <Route exact path="/Slider" component={Slider}/>
        <Route path="/Signup" component={Signup}/>
        <Route path="/Login" component={Login}/>
    </div>
</Router>,
```

How can I change my routing for it to work on 'build', and also what is a better way to set my routing?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work in local, with `npm start` ? Or is the problem only with build ?

Comment: With 'npm start' it's works fine. The problem is only with the build.

Comment: This is because the build only generates a root index.html file. In the case of static hosting the path /login will try to access a file called login.html, which does not exist in the build.